# Capture Both image And Video Using same Intent In Android

Tags: android, video-capture, android-camera-intent, image-capture

I am trying to capture still Image and Video using same intent like default camera app. Don't want to Create custom camera.

Android allows me to either take picture or Capture video.

Is it possible and How.If not why?

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "capture still Image and Video using same intent" means.

Comment: can you just grab a frame from the video to produce a still image?

Comment: Thanks everyone for replay. 
@CommonsWare   "capture still Image and Video using same intent"  means I want to capture Both Image and Video using a single Intent. Like Image capture intent.

Comment: @rothloup "grab a frame from the video to produce a still image" for that I have to save video first, I don't think so during recording using Intent it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely impossible to have Android take photo and take video simultaneously, as a software limitation not a hardware one.

It would require:

- modified framework jars (to process both files),
- modified kernel (to process both intents),
- modified drivers/HAL (to capture RAW output into a jpg and mp4 simultaneously,
- and modified Camera app (to provide the API).

**A better approach** would be to take the video and pull a frame out of it. You can find/use libraries to process videos or you can take a look at AOSP source for thumbnail caching for code examples.

Comment: Thank you sir, for your replay, I am looking for   solution you have suggested.

Comment: any solution for this?